# replace iteration in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to replace occurrences of string with different values (from dictionary).

```
string = 'asfd @@@ fdsfd @@@ ffds @@@ asdf'
kv = {1: 'hi', 2: 'there', 3: 'bla'}
```

Expected:

```
string = 'asfd hi fdsfd there ffds bla asdf'
```

I've tried several solutions particularly with .replace or re.sub but still didn't find a good one.

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A one-line solution:

```
string.replace('@@@', '{}', len(kv)).format(*kv.values())
```

Short explanation:

- Replace all `'@@@'` strings with the python string formatting identifier `'{}'`. `len(kv)` reduces the number of replaces to the length of the dict, avoiding `IndexError` when the dict has less elements than the number of `'@@@'` in the string
- extract dictionary values with `kv.values()`
- unpack dictionary values with `*kv.values()` and pass this as argument to the string `format` method.

Sample code execution:
Input

```
string = 'asfd @@@ fdsfd @@@ ffds @@@ asdf'
kv = {'1': 'hi', '2': 'there', '3': 'bla'}
```

And output

```
string.replace('@@@', '{}', len(kv)).format(*kv.values())
#Out: 'asfd hi fdsfd there ffds bla asdf'
```

Advantage of this solution:
No explicit looping (explicit looping is almost always a bad idea in python) and only one line of code. Furthermore this is **also working** when the **number of `'@@@'` is less **or** greater than the number of values in `kv`**, when the `count` parameter in `str.replace` is specified.

---

This leads to the **final** and 99% **failsafe** variant of my solution, using the `len` of the dict as `count` argument in `replace`:

```
string.replace('@@@', '{}', len(kv)).format(*kv.values())
```

Comment: For a fixed number of `@` this should be the accepted solution (+1).

Comment: this is great! I only needed to modify the key in dictionary from string to int ('1' vs 1) to make it work properly, as string was messing up the order but string.replace('@@@', '{}', len(kv)).format(*kv.values()) was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! What python version do you use? <=3.5? If you update to 3.6+, dicts will be ordered by creation order, meaning that the key does not influence the order.

Comment: Just remember that dicts will be ordered when updating to 3.6+, thus some results without explicitly selecting values by keys may change.

Answer (score 3):

This is one approach using `str.replace` with optional parameter `count`.

**Ex:**

```
s = 'asfd @@@ fdsfd @@@ ffds @@@ asdf'
kv = {'1': 'hi', '2': 'there', '3': 'bla'}

for k, v in sorted(kv.items()):
    s = s.replace("@@@", v, 1)
print(s)
```

**[MoreInfo](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace)**

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.sub` to get the job done with out any sorting

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
>   occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the
>   pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. repl can be a
>   string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it
>   are processed.

```
import re
string = 'asfd @@@ fdsfd @@@ ffds @@@ asdf'
kv = {'1': 'hi', '2': 'there', '3': 'bla'}
class repl:
    def __init__(self):
        self.called=0
    def __call__(self,match):
        self.called+=1
        return kv[str(self.called)]
print(re.sub('@@@',repl(),string))
```

OUTPUT

```
asfd hi fdsfd there ffds bla asdf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'asfd @@@ fdsfd @@@ ffds @@@ asdf'
kv = {1: 'hi', 2: 'there', 3: 'bla'}

for k,v in kv.items():
    string = string.replace('@@@', v, 1)
print(string)
```

OUTPUT:

```
asfd hi fdsfd there ffds bla asdf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kv = {'1': 'hi', '2': 'there', '3': 'bla'}
string = 'asfd @@@ fdsfd @@@ ffds @@@ asdf'
string_list=string.split('@@@')
string_list_out=[]
for i in range(len(string_list)):
    if i==0:
        string_list_out.append(string_list[0])
    else:
        string_list_out.append(kv[str(i)])
        string_list_out.append(string_list[i])

string_list_out=''.join(string_list_out)
print(string_list_out)
   'asfd hi fdsfd there ffds bla asdf'
```